Set location permission on "always" on apps such as Strava
I'm working on a tracking app like Strava or Runkeeper so I need to received location in background. What I've done so far is asking for the access background location permission and the location permission but the prompt only shows three options:

Allow only while using the app
Ask every time
Deny

But what I need is the "Always" options. It is a very poor experience for the user navigate to settings and check the always option. Otherwise android will stop tracking the user from the moment he locks the phone.
But It seems that the app Strava does no need to do that, it works un background with de "allow only while using the app"
How can I achieve that?
